# Would spells played with Enchanted Evening in play trigger Mesa Enchantress?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

With [Enchanted Evening](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=151979), all permanents are also enchantments.  [Mesa Enchantress](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220116) allows you to draw when you play an enchantment.  If I have both out, and play a creature, do I get to draw a card?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, because Enchanted Evening does not change the card type of spells on the stack.**

The Enchantress' [Oracle wording](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220116) makes this clearer:

> Whenever you cast an enchantment spell, you may draw a card.

"Casting" refers to the action of putting a spell on the stack.

Enchanted Evening only affects permanents. It will do so from the very moment they enter the battlefield, so they enter the battlefield as enchantments. But the spell that creates the permanent (which is the game object that's represented by the card on the stack) isn't an enchantment spell.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  I was thinking "comes into play", not casting/playing

Comment: Yeah, the old use of "play" for "cast" makes for quite a bit of confusion. :/

Answer (score -3):

Yes it does, this ruling hasn't changed, and probably wont since its very rare to use.

"Captain Sisay" Searches your library for legendary card.

A card retains all text relevant to the card anywhere except rfg. Note the card says 'All permanents are enchantments.' Not 'All permanents you control...' This ruling is used a lot pre-eight. And will more than likely not change since most formats that allow pre-eight cards are considered casual.

Hope this has helped.

Comment: I'm very confused. What does Captain Sisay have to do with this, or whether or not the permanent's under your control? What ruling? Is this the question you actually intended to answer, or did you accidentally answer a different question?

Comment: most formats pre-eight includes vintage and legacy, possibly the furthest formats from casual (at least, pricetag wise) in the entirety of MTG, im not sure what other formats you are thinking of that qualify these sets as casual only. The answer is wrong, as cards are only permanents if they are on the battlefield. "You control" only prevents the card affecting opponent's permanents. Cards in other zones are just that, cards, not permanents.